# IIS web.config changes to disable request filtering are no longer working

Tags: iis, request, web-config, filtering

Running Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 with the latest patches. It seems something has broken with request filtering.

Has anyone found a solution to prevent query strings like the following resulting in 403 errors:

https://someurl.com/somescript.aspx?startdate=5/17/2017

-OR-

https://someurl.com/somescript.aspx?sometext=I%20select%20Joe%20for%20the%20soccer%20team.

The first one fails due to the date. The second fails due to the "%20select%20".  The request filter must think it's an SQL injection.

In the past, turning off request validation in web.config worked to fix this. Now, it doesn't.   I also tried using the request filtering tags and using a clear inside of all of them in an attempt to override something that might be inheriting. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  New settings were pushed to the Host Intrusion Protection software running on the web server and it was doing the additional filtering.